# Erro no npm run watch - Cannot read property 'install' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, webpack

Esse erro ocorre quando faço um "npm run watch".
Quando faço um "npm run dev", não da este erro.

Ja reinstalei todo o npm e não resolveu...
alguma solução?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]